# OpenLiteSpeedで.htaccessを利用できるようにする方法

Tags: .htaccess

お世話になっております。
ApacheからOpenLiteSpeedへ切り替えようとしています。
とりあえず、バーチャルホストを設定して、ドメイン名でアクセスできるようにはなったのですが、.htaccessが読み込まれていないようです。
.htaccessにはエラーメッセージを指定する下記の行が記載されているだけとなります。

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

また、その他のファイルにアクセスできることはすでに確認しています。
.htaccessを読み込むようにするには、何か設定が必要なのでしょうか。
ちなみに、[OpenLiteSpeedでhtaccessを使う方法](https://www.logw.jp/cloudserver/9048.html)を参考に、「Rewriteを有効にする」と「Auto Load from .htaccess」の両方を「はい」にしてみましたが、変化なしでした。
また、上記サイトにもあるとおり、Rewrite ルールに

```
<ドキュメントルートのパス]/.htaccess
```

も追加してみましたが、変わらずでした。
環境は、Ubuntu 18.04、OpenLiteSpeed Ver.1.4.46です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: これ [OpenLiteSpeedでhtaccessを使う方法](https://www.logw.jp/cloudserver/9048.html) みたいです。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。ただ、教えていただいたサイトを参考に設定してみましたが、やはりうまくいかないようです。一応その旨も追記しておきました。

Comment: 有効性は不明ですが、参考になるかもしれない記事です。 [Migrate Apache Rewrite Rules to OpenLiteSpeed](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/migrate-apache-rewrite-rules-to-openlitespeed/)、[Ubuntu 16.04 LTSにインストールしたWebサーバーLiteSpeed にインストールしたWordPressをマルチサイト化](https://ts0818.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/21/185846)、[How should I configure/rewrite CakePHP's htaccess for openlitespeed based server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48701443/9014308)、[How to use Magento 2 with an openlitespeed (free) web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53581637/9014308)

Comment: どうもOpenLiteSpeedでは、.htaccessの利用が制限されているようで、自分がやりたいことはできなさそうなことがわかりました。いろいろ調べてくださり、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

お世話になります。
あれからいろいろ調べていたんですが、OpenLiteSpeedでは、.htaccessの動作が制限されているようです。

https://www.litespeedtech.com/products/litespeed-web-server/editions

Enterprise版を利用すればうまくいくとは思いますが、とりあえず、OpenLiteSpeedは諦めてApacheを利用しようと思います。
ありがとうございました。